# slide out animation not working on back press button?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-animation

I am using animations when entering or exiting the activity,entering to an activity animation works fine but exit animation does not work well. I start exit animation when i press back button.What happens is it first start enter animation for current activity then show the last activity what i want a simple exit animation on back button press.

**Slide_out.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" >

</translate>
```

Slide_in.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" >

</translate>
```

**On Action bar back button pressed**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:

        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);
        return true;


    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Suppose you have a ActivityA now from where you want your ActivityB to come from and how ActivityB will exit. Please explain a little so i can help

Comment: I want to start B from with enter animation. I am able to do it. but i want to go to previous activity(A) from B with exit animation like left to right.How can i do it ?

Comment: so you need ActivityB to slide from left over your ActivityA and on Back press you want ActivityB to slide to right where as your ActivityA will remain as it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used 
slide_in.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >

</translate>
```

**slide_out.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" >

</translate>
```

**slide_enter.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >

</translate>
```

**slide_exit.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" >

</translate>
```

**Code**

```
        Intent i=new Intent(Authentication.this,Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

To previous

```
         finish();
         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
```

Comment: Copying the answer of someone who answered your own question is ridiculous. I don't even know how you got so many upvotes.

Comment: This answer is correct. But `slide_out.xml` seems to be irrelevant. Using `android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"` works without any visible difference, too.

Answer (score 31):

Firstly create one more animation i.e nothing.xml in your anim folder

**nothing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >

</translate>
```

here is your **slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >

</translate>
```

and **slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" >

</translate>
```

Now call your NewActivity like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.nothing);
```

and then on your back button click do this

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Comment: how  can move the A activity coming in. when B is exiting

Comment: but you said you want ActivityA to stay there as it is??

Comment: Sorry i just have a change in requirement.

Comment: lol just change R.anim.nothing to R.anim.slide_in  on your back button press

Comment: It looks like you can replace the nothing.xml with 0 like: 
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_out);

Comment: You can try that but I guess it will show some black screen while transition. not sure though but there should be some reason I didn't use 0. You can try that out and let me know. Thanks ..!!

Comment: Answer is slightly wrong: Layout `slide_in.xml` must be `android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"` instead of `android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"`. The new activity should come from the left and not from the right.

Comment: you dont need to use new anim file. Just use overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim. slide_out) in onCreate and finish

Answer (score 5):

Add animation in `onBackPressed`, it will show the animation while clicking the back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);   
}
```

Comment: I am using the back button on action bar. I have shown the code for that

Comment: oops, sorry. What about replacing the finish with call it by using intent.Like this.                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);

Comment: But that would kill my previous activity & all data will be lost.

Comment: K. Dude can you please check with  onBackPressed() function calling like this.  case R.id.home:
       onBackPressed();
        return true;  I dont know it will work or not its a guess.

Comment: What i want on back previous activity should start from left

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by overriding the back button behavior.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similiar and it works fine, you can change animate() with startAnimation(your_xml), you will also have to make activity background transparent:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

This activity will slide down, and the MainActivity will be visible at the moment of sliding because of transparent background.
EDIT - with toolbar back button:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mainlinear.animate()
                    .translationY(ScUtils.getScreenHeight(getApplicationContext()))
                    .setDuration(210)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            ThemeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                           }
                          }).start();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I am using the action bar back button here so tell the way out for that

Answer (score 0):

For the Activity enter animation use `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_in);` in the `onCreate(...)` function.

For the exit animation place the same call in `onPause(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a back/home button on my action bar which was not picking up the slide animation by overriding `onBackPressed` or `finish`. So I had to add this snippet from [here](https://www.warpdesign.fr/android-replace-default-transitions-with-slides-in-activities/). If using the same `slide_enter` and `slide_exit` as above:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        // back button
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In case somebody finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to or from an Activity, pop animations are not applied automatically.

Once the animation is added to the navigation XML, it must be added to the target activity an override of [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) with [applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions#activity) to have the pop exit animation.

```
 override fun finish() {
    super.finish()
    ActivityNavigator.applyPopAnimationsToPendingTransition(this)
}
```