# Android activity back transition brakes when going back 2 screens

Tags: android, android-animation, android-support-library, android-transitions

I made a simple sample to prove that there is something wrong with `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity)`.

I got 3 activities: A, B & C.
Flow is simple: A -> B -> C

All activities share the same style:

```
<style name="TransitionsTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/slide_in_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/slide_out_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

Whenever I go: `A -> B -> C -> B (back button) -> A (back button)` last animation`(A -> C)` is not played.

It works fine when only doing `A -> B -> A (back button)`

Here is how I start activities:

```
fun start(activity: Activity) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, TransitionActivityA::class.java) //or B or C
            val transitionsOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity)
            activity.startActivity(intent, transitionsOptions.toBundle())
        }
```

App demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/jkwiecien/AndroidCaseStudies/tree/transitions
Use branch `transitions`

Is that an Android bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try to  override Activity's `onBackPressed`  with calling to `overridePendingTransition()` method?  like in answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512662/slide-out-animation-not-working-on-back-press-button/28512750

Comment: `A -> B -> C -> B (back button) -> A (back button)` - What does it mean? From `C` to `B` -> `back button` to `A` -> `back button` to (expected) `C` ??? OR from `C` -> `back button` to `B` -> `back buttton` to `A` ??? In any case, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack) might help you.

Comment: seems to work fine on emulator (api 24 and api 27), is it specific to some Android APIs?

Comment: yes, It doesn't work on API 30 in my case, but works fine on 23 and 24.

Comment: Launchmode sometimes messes with Transitions, if you use anything other than the default one that might be the source of it

Answer (score -1):

It does not work, because `ActivityB` is "started" by `ActivityC`, while it did work for the transition to `ActivityB`, because `ActivityC` is started by it.

It seems that you have to override `onBackPressed()` and start `ActivityA` from `ActivityB` manually, using reversed `ActivityOptions`. The only way of doing that is calling `overridePendingTransition()` after `finish()`.